# bash syntax for string and number comparision

Tags: bash

Why does bash use `-lt, -eq`
 etc for number comparison, and ==, != etc for string comparison ?

Bash syntax has its quirks which make it difficult to write and remember, but this seems completely non-intuitive for a simple use case.

Source : [bash syntax][1]http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html

Comment: Hmm, not sure if there's gonna be an answer any better than "because it does"!

Comment: Have you read [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)?

Comment: Because legacy. Bash inherited a lot of its syntax from the 1960s and 70s, back when a "programming language" was a novel thing. It can't be changed now because it would break everything, but additional syntax has been introduced so you can do `(( n < 3 ))` instead of `[ "$n" -le 3 ]`

Comment: earlier I tried learning csh script but due to weird syntax, always gave up and googled a throwaway script. Now I am trying to figure out all weirdness behind whitespace , braces , quotes usage etc. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: For backward compatibility, that syntax goes back to at least the 1980s, long before Bash was born (or should that be bourne?).  Also to conform to the POSIX standards http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html.  Some features came from the korn shell.  So don't blame bash.  There are plenty of other shells if you don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` only has one type: strings. More richly typed languages can overload (e.g.) the `>` operator to perform string comparison or numerical comparison based on the types of the arguments. Lacking anything other than a string type, `bash` must have separate operators for the different operations. Compare

```
[[ 9 > 10 ]] # exit status 0; 9 is lexicographically greater than 10
[[ 9 -gt 10 ]] # exit status 1; 9 is not numerically greater than 10
```

You can, however, use the normal operators for numbers if you use them inside an arithmetic expression, where `bash` assumes *all* values are either numbers or variables with numerical values.

```
(( 9 > 10 ))  # exit status 1, 9 is not numerically greater than 10
(( 9 > foo )) # same as [[ 9 -gt $foo ]]
```

Comment: awk does the overload thing and the result is sometimes very surprising. So it could also have been a design decision, if you can manage to apply the word "design" to bash while keeping a straight face.